# Caching page load in jQuery tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

My html:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="~/WebAppOne">Web App One</a></li>
        <li><a href="~/WebAppTwo">Web App Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs( {
        cache: true
    } );
} );
```

The problem is I want the tab content to load just one time.  It loads first time just fine, but if I click between tabs, it is reloading the page.  So if a user had entered something into a form on WebAppOne, switching to WebAppTwo and back will nuke their changes.

So first, is `cache:true` what I want?  Or does it just cache the page like a normal browser?  Ideally I would want to load all tabs content areas asynchronously when the page loads, and then never again- regardless of how they click around.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are the pages being found? Are you using asp.net? I think you need to resolve those urls.

Comment: Use `cache:true` and possibly `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });`?

Comment: Nope didn't work :(  I need some sort of 'load once' setting.  Everytime I click on a tab it's hitting the server- and wiping out form data (just as Kevin B describes in the answer below)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want, but I'm thinking you need to use hrefs like #WebAppOne. And use AJAX calls to populate the tab content once on the initial page load (or just build all the content before you serve the page).

Comment: @ToddGibson That's pretty much what I'm working on now- seems there's no way with jquery tab to just do a 'load once' call.  It always loads on every click.

Comment: You know though the docs are pretty clear `Whether or not to cache remote tabs content, e.g. load only once or with every click. Cached content is being lazy loaded, e.g once and only once for the first click.` But this isn't working for me... I must be doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your web server sends cache control headers, and the browser honors those caching will "magically happen".

http://condor.depaul.edu/dmumaugh/readings/handouts/SE435/HTTP/node24.html

Comment: However this won't solve his problem. Even if the page is cached, form data will be lost when it is retrieved, regardless of whether it was retrieved from browser cache or a new version was requested.